# The Diophantine equation $x^p - 4y^p = z^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $p \geq 5$ is a prime, are there any integers $x, y, z > p$ such that
$(x, y) = 1$ 
and
$$x^{p} - 4y^{p} = z^{2}$$

Comment: $78^3-4\times29^3=614^2$. $93^3-4\times53^3=457^2$.

Comment: Ah fantastic. Appreciated. Then I have to strengthen the lower bound. The first version of my question is for $p \geq 3,$ and that's why Gerry Myerson left the comment.

Comment: Note that my earlier comment referred to an earlier version of the question.

Comment: If there were infinitely many, it would contradict the abc conjecture.

Comment: Well if there were infinitely many solutions, it would contradict a Theorem of Darmon and Granville!  See http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/12.Granville/paper.pdf .

Comment: @Lucia The finiteness of Darmon and Granville is for fixed $p$. ABC implies finiteness even if $p$ is allowed to vary. Of course, the results you cite in your answer settle the matter.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: Good point!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your examples are also helpful [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902973/the-diophantine-equation-xp-4yp-z2-with-x-y-1-and-x-y-z-p/903102#903102).

Comment: @Dietrich, there are more where those came from, I think eight examples with $x<1000$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Theorem 1.2 of the paper by [Bennett and Skinner](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BS.pdf), which settles the problem for $p\ge 7$ (take there $C=1$ and $\alpha_0=2$).   Note that the Bennett-Skinner results are more general. (Earlier work of [Darmon and Granville](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/12.Granville/paper.pdf) (using Faltings's theorem) showed that there are only finitely many solutions; again for more general such equations.)

Finally GH from MO has kindly pointed out an earlier paper of [Darmon](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/08.Fermat-nn23/paper.pdf) that handles this particular equation (assuming Shimura-Taniyama) for $p=11$ or $p\ge 17$.

Comment: Actually Darmon already proved in 1993 that, assuming the Shimura-Taniyama conjecture, there are no nonzero solutions for $p\geq 17$ and for $p=11$. See Proposition 2.5 in his paper (Internat. Math. Res. Notices 1993, 263–274).

Comment: @GHfromMO: Thanks for pointing that out! I'll also add a link to Darmon's paper.

Comment: And very similar result were proved by Ivorra, see Acta Arith. 108 (2003), 327–338.

Comment: And also by Siksek, see J. Théor. Nombres Bordeaux 15 (2003), 839–846.

Comment: Thanks so much. I wish I can vote you up more than once.